# Are there really no controllers or views generated for Sentry?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am using Laravel, and wanted some auth functionality.  The 2 leaders as far as packages are concerned seem to be [Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) and [Sentry](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry).

I tried Confide initially, but lost confidence (ironically) in it almost instantly when the generated login view created errors (seems the migration didn't add a username field), along with other views after that problem was fixed.

So now I am trying Sentry.  However, despite being popular, it seems that Sentry still requires a lot of work to get a very basic auth system up and running.  From what I can tell there are no routes, views or controllers generated, so a lot of the grunt work still has to be done manually.  Confide set up all of the views, routes and controllers for me so after install I could literally just visit /users/create and see the sign up form.

Am I right in thinking there is no way to generate these routes, views and controllers for Sentry?  If that is the case I see little benefit to using Sentry over using the built in Auth, aside from perhaps the login throttling features.

Comment: Laravel 5 has some of this stuff built in from the beginning

Comment: @TheShiftExchange really?  Have you got a link for that?  http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication doesn't mention it from what I can see.

Comment: Just install it and see. You have an Auth and Password Controller. All routes and views are included.